# ExpandableListView - A checkbox as indicator for expanded or not

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

This is what I have, I Expandable listview. Each Group item is a Checkbox witha Textview next to it.

I want that checkbox to be toggled checked/unchecked if the group is expanded or not expanded.

Also vica versa, so if the checkbox is checked, the list should be expanded etc.

Any ideas?

this is my group_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_channel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks pretty, just need it to check and uncheck .

Answer (score 2):

Ah ok, this is how i Did it

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) { 
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = newGroupView(isExpanded, parent);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }

    if ( isExpanded ) {
        ((CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check_channel)).setChecked(true);
    } else {
        ((CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check_channel)).setChecked(false);
    }
    bindGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, v, parent);
    return v;
}
```